# Facebook Canvas URL returns blank page

Tags: facebook

This is what I get even though "Canvas URL" and "Secure Canvas URL" is specified withing the app settings: https://apps.facebook.com/280434655456932

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the app live? because it redirects from canvas to the app centre and then there is an empty page. no "blank page" though.

Comment: Your app URL, https://solidmediagroup.com/appstr/?app=444, when called via a POST request, issues an (invalid) 302 redirect with `Location: ./login` – is that desired behavior …?